# Maria DB configuration on Swisscom cloud

Tags: mysql, cloud, my.cnf, swisscomdev, mariasql

We are going to use next stack: Tomcat 8/Java 8 buildpacked + ELK + S3 + Maria DB.

We prepared our package and deployments process is starting ok, but we are stuck on configuring Maria DB. More specifically we need at least next parameters to be set in my.cnf file of the Maria (Mysql):

`lower_case_table_names = 1
transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
character-set-server = utf8`

Does anyone know how to do this? Because only thing we found that could be used is next from Swisscom Manual ->
https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/devguide/services/managing-services.html "Update a Service Instance" section, but there is no chance to find Maria DB service parameters that could be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swisscom's MariaDB offering is a Galera Cluster shared for all customers. The customers have their own database.

Customers can't modify global `my.cnf` parameters. The global config is the same for every customer.

The team is currently in progress optimise the Galera cluster, stay tuned, soon the default MariaDB parameter will be much better for DBaaS. Still you can't modify global variables.

Customer can modify [session variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-system-variables.html)

> There are two scopes in which system variables exist. Global variables
>   affect the overall operation of the server. Session variables affect
>   its operation for individual client connections. A given system
>   variable can have both a global and a session value.

Most (not all) variables can be also defined on a session level.

*To be more specific for your questions*

You can set in your code for each transaction the preferred level

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ-COMMITTED;
```

The variable [lower_case_table_names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) have only global scope and you can't set it per session.

> Variable Scope    Global

```
> show global variables like 'lower_case_table_names';
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| lower_case_table_names | 0     |
+------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The character set and collation can be set for each table. See [Table Character Set and Collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-table.html)

Every table has a table character set and a table collation. The `CREATE TABLE` and `ALTER TABLE` statements have optional clauses for specifying the table character set and collation.